# How effective is multi-threading vs sequential processing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a unit of work on a .NET 4.51, C# Web Service that takes 100 milliseconds.  Usually the web request contains 10 units of work or so.  Thus processing it sequentially via a for loop takes about a second.

```
foreach (var u in unitsOfWork) {
  Run(u);
}
```

Since the box has 12 CPUs, I decided to split up the work and run it in parallel hoping to get a performance gain.  I used `Parallel.ForEach` to do the work:

```
Parallel.ForEach(unitsOfWork,u => {
    Run(u);
});
```

To my surprise, each unit of work took on average 425 milliseconds.  So in the end I saved about 500 milliseconds off the request.  It seems like I should be able to get better performance seeing how the box has 12 CPUs...  Am I missing something simple?

I looked for anything that is shared (that could be holding it up), but found nothing...so I tried to experiment.  I sent a request with 2 units of work and each took about 125 ms.  With 3 requests each unit took 150 ms and so on.  With each subsequent number of units, there was a penalty of around 25 to 30 ms.

So either I am doing something wrong... or there is just inherent overhead to multi-threading (didn't realize it was this big).

P.S. I also tried replacing Parallel.For with Thread.Join - same results.

Comment: Starting threads has overhead, plus you might also run into I/O contention (e.g. if all threads read from the filesystem, I/O could be a limiting factor).

Comment: I recommend running a good profiler (the one built-in to Visual Studio can work in a pinch) to examine what's occurring.  The sources of contention can sometimes be surprising, though often it boils down to I/O or some internally locked API call.

Comment: What's in your "unit of work"? You say math and shuffling of data between collections and grouping of results in the comment to the answer below. So no persistence or retrieval at all, all in-memory operations? If so, then it could be cache trashing as mentioned by @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @odyss-jii Yeah, basically all in-memory operations.  I am willing to concede that there is an overhead and/or cache thrashing... but a jump from 100ms to 425ms.  That's a pretty harsh jump.  Is there a way to 1) detect cache thrashing and 2) overcome it?

Comment: @AngryHacker You should be able to get information on L2-cache misses using the Visual Studio profiler (CPU Counters - Memory Events - Last Level Cache Misses). As far as I know, the L2-cache is usually shared on multi-core processors so could cause a problem if the size of the data you are working on in each thread is large. Since there is no retrieval, I'm guessing that you allocate a lot of data? How large are the collections you shuffle and do you allocate them once or are there several allocations in the algorithm (during the shuffling for example)?

Comment: @odyss-jii Yes, there are a lot of allocations...  Each unit of work probably allocates 2-4 MB of data.  Anyway, I enabled the Server GC (so that it can collect garbage in multi-threaded fashion) and, holy smokes, it really kicked up the performance a whole bunch.  Now each line processes in around 150 ms.

Answer (score 6):

The theoretical [*speedup*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) that you could achieve is governed by [*Amdahl's law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law):

[image: Amdahl's law]

where `T(1)` is the single-threaded speed, `n` is the number of CPUs, and `B` is the percentage of the task that *cannot* be serialized. The overhead of starting up a new task is considered to be zero by this formula.

If your task were perfectly parallelizable, `B` would be zero, and you would complete the task in 1/12-th of the time. However, even a modest `B` of, say, 20%, would limit the highest potential speedup with 12 CPUs to only 3.75 times - a little over a third of the theoretical limit of 12 times.

Things that cannot be parallelized include serialized access to shared resources, such as I/O and waiting on completion of other tasks.

Dealing with cache contentions makes matters even worse: when concurrent tasks are accessing different regions of memory, they kick the data of each other out of hardware cache, which amounts to increasing `B` in the formula above.

To summarize, your observation is not uncommon, and you are not missing anything. Achieving a theoretically possible sppedup is very hard, and the actual speedup that you achieve depends on the tasks that your parallel program needs to run.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like I should be able to get better performance seeing how the box has 12 CPUs... Am I missing something simple?

Yes, your work isn't CPU bound work.  You're performing a network request.  That's IO bound work.  The bottleneck is not in time spent by your CPU performing operations, but rather by your network connection.  Clearly it can increase throughput by performing more than one request at a time, but it can only scale up so much before it has saturated the connection.  What that point is will have nothing to do with how many CPUs you have.

Note that there is no need for multiple threads here at all to achieve parallelism.  You can simply make some number of the web service requests asynchronously, and then wait for all of the asynchronous requests to complete after starting them all to parallelize the operations while only ever having a *single* thread.  Assuming the actual CPU bound work you do on the results of the web service calls isn't significant, this could even improve your performance by being able to remove all of the overhead of threading while still parallelizing most of the work.

Comment: I should have mentioned it in the post.  The "work" in the unit of work is almost all math.  The rest of it is shuffling data between collections and grouping the results.  So the part that I measure is theoretically CPU bound (and I do see CPUs spike up in the Task Manager).  The entire Web Service call does have I/O, but that is not the part that I measure.

Comment: @AngryHacker Then the difference between 12x speedup and what you got represents overhead of threading, combined with operations that couldn't be performed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that some of your work involves shuffling data between collections.  Are those collections shared between threads? Do you take locks when you read/write those collections?  If so (and depending upon exactly what you need to do with those collections), you might be able to get better scale by being more "chunky" with your collection -- is there a way to arrange your work such that your reads/writes to the collections all occur before/after the threads complete?